# Disable single Google Tag Manager Container?

Tags: google-tag-manager

My site has multiple GTM containers with different tags/triggers already setup.

I want to disable the tracking for certain containers without losing all of the event/trigger data.

Is it possible to just disable specific containers in GTM or will I need to delete the container?

Thanks in advance for your help, internet!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable a container all at once, but there are workarounds:

- create a trigger, type "custom event", enter ".*" as event name and
  enable regex parsing. Then add this to all your tags as an trigger
  exception. Since this fires on any event if will block all triggers
- create a new container in your account. Export the empty container. Import the empty container as a new version in your current container and publish. The old data will still be available as previous version and you can roll back to that version at any time.
- The somewhat obvious way: Leave the container as it is, but remove the GTM snippet from your website.